# Can't Empty Spam Comments in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, comments, spam

Does anybody know why I would be redirected to home page when I press the "Empty Spam" button in WordPress Admin Panel?

The same thing happens if I mark multiple spam comments and delete them. The system will redirect me to the home page, and the supposedly deleted comments will not be removed.

I deleted all core files and re-added again, deactivated all plugins, and even changed my theme to the WordPress default. None of these actions helped.

Comment: Hi Dan. Have you checked your server's error logs?

Comment: Yes. Nothing there. Checked in my FTP too and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking .htaccess for strange stuff - like redirects other than the standard WordPress redirect block - and try resaving permalinks from `Dashboard >> Permalinks`.

In case you have thousands of spam comments and WordPress might be timing out, you can use this query in [Adminer « WordPress Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/) to delete all spam and trashed comments.

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments where comment_approved='spam' OR comment_approved='trash'
```